# how does program counter stores the instruction memory when program is loaded?

Tags: computer-architecture, mips

it is mentioned in the book ***computer organization and design by Patterson/Hennessy page 252*** that:

> The instruction memory need only provide read access because the
>   datapath does not write instructions. Since the instruction memory
>   only reads, we treat it as combinational logic: the output at any time
>   reflects the contents of the location specified by the address input,
>   and no read control signal is needed. (***We will need to write the
>   instruction memory when we load the program;*** this is not hard to add,
>   and we ignore it for simplicity.)

*my question is*: how is storing instruction memory when the program is loaded possible?? should we add an *enable* to PC which activates by operating system and the operating system then writes the address in PC?? or there are other ways??

here is a simple figure of PC and instruction memory

[image: pc and instruction memory]

Comment: The instruction memory is writable by *some* means. IT can be either regular RAM, some kind of programmable ROM or one-time programmable logic. Not clear what PC is related to this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. PC is just a register that contains the address of the current instruction being executed

Comment: I know what PC is. It is not clear how it is related to the rest of your question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know whether it can be related or not. I just simply want to know how to do the thing mentioned in parenthesis in the quote. I thought that PC may be participated

Comment: PC is related to executing a program --> Fetch --> execute cycle. This is in no way related to how the data was originally placed in the instruction memory during a programming cycle.

Comment: @JackCreasey so this means that we should change the instruction memory. right??

Comment: @JackCreasey I thought that because instructions are placed somewhere in memory we only need to initialize PC at the begining. and the instruction memory will do the rest of the work(loading the first instruction and ...)

Comment: You load the program before you run it, why is this so hard to understand? In the old times you just halt the computer and insert punch cards. When you done loading it, you set PC to the location in memory where entry point of your program is and un-halt the computer. How else could you do this? On modern PC the boot process is still the same, except boot loader does it for you.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi The instruction memory does NO work. It is simply memory accessed by the fetch/execute cycle of whatever processor you use. All the work is done in the logic or firmware of the execution unit.

Comment: bits is bits, an answer below goes into further detail, but assuming this is ram, then you can do data cycles to fill in the memory and then instruction cycles to read it out.  Puttting the bits somewhere does not use the program counter and it is not instructions at that point it is some form of data it does not become instructions until it is parsed by the decode/fetch/execute...and even there on branches some non-instructions can be fed into a pipe, perhaps not in the textbook case, but in general certainly.

Comment: the program counter is not used to perform writes, it is used to perform reads.  (it could be used to execute instructions that perform writes, sure).

Answer (score 3):

Essentially all the text is saying is that somehow the program gets loaded into memory before the CPU can start running it.  Since the text only intends to discuss how the CPU executes instructions out of program memory, how the instructions end up in program memory in the first place is an implementation detail.

There are many ways of getting the instructions into program memory, and it is highly dependent on the architecture.

Systems based on read-only memory will have the instructions loaded into program memory either during manufacture of the chip itself (with a mask ROM) or with external programming hardware that writes to the memory array.

Systems that contain flash memory often have some self-programming mechanism where the processor can either execute special instructions or write to special registers to trigger an erase or write operation on program memory.  The CPU may have to be stopped temporarily to allow the operation to complete.

A standard desktop computer that executes out of RAM and loads programs off of a hard drive has a much more complex process.  In this case, the initial boot would be done out of a flash ROM of some sort, possibly copied into RAM by components on the motherboard before the main CPU is allowed to start running.  Then this startup code will load more code into RAM from a hard drive or solid state drive.  A desktop or server CPU actually doesn't even execute code out of RAM, it executes code out of on-chip cache memory, which is in turn loaded from RAM.  Because of this, it is possible that the CPU to run software out of cache while memory operations take place to do other things, including copying other executable code from a hard drive and into RAM.  The CPU also has stop and wait occasionally when the code it wants to run is not in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question, how can you fix a car while driving.

The processor does not need the instruction memory all the time, it latches the instruction in a register (or many instructions in a queue). Until processing it the instruction memory, data and addresses,  can be accessed by the processor itself or by some other coprocessor.

If the writing to instruction memory is fast like a RAM memory it can be done in one step then PC gets the addresses back and next instruction can be read from instruction memory. In this time the addresses are handled by a different register.

If it's a long process like in flash memories then somebody else does that, usually the instruction memory is organized in banks the bank that is in the writing process is not available for reading instructions. The processor is sending the data to the programming engine while executing instructions from a different bank.

Of course, the initial code, the bootloader that tells the processor how to load a program is written by external means, in the factory, using programmers etc without the processor intervention.